# Download android Support Annotations jar

Tags: android

The following line shows error stating 'Cannot find symbol annotation'

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
```

Where do I download the android-support-annotations jar that contains this annotation ?

Comment: it is within the appcompat lib.

Comment: I'm new to Android studio, can you please list the steps to include the same ? Is it some external jar I need to download ?

Comment: Why do you need jar in case you are using android studio you can just add this line `compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'` to the gradle file inside app module. This will do everything under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to android SDK folder, in my case this is /home/kiwitech/Android/Sdk
2. Open  extras folder (you see android and google folder)
3. Open android folder
4. Open support folder.
5. Open annotation folder

Your required jar is in annotation folder.

You can add the jar file in the android studio as follows:

1. Add a folder in your project named "libs"(if not exist) and keep the jar files inside this folder , which you want to use in your project.
2. You will be able to see the jar file from android studio. Right click on the jar file and select the option "Add as Library" and Click Ok.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @CROSP solved my problem!
just add this line to you dependencies
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'